# Can you have an eventhandler for an image in the image class

Tags: java, image, eventhandler, mouseclick-event

Is it possible to associate a image from the Image class not image view with a click eventhandler? (Javafx)
Many thanks

Comment: No, because it isn't a `Node`. Anyway, it only represents the image, not what the user sees. Why would you need such a functionality?